# Regular Expression match year YYYY but up to 2020

Tags: python, regex, range

I need to match birthdays up to the current year in MMM-DD-YYYY. However I'm stuck on tackling the year bit as I'm unsure if there is a better way to match up to a range (eg up to 2020) other than individually matching the numbers 2-0-2-0 and how to set restrictions on the year so it doesn't surpass 2020.

edit: It's for an assignment, so **I can't use datetime or other libraries** to do this. It has to be completely regex.

```
pattern ="^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-[0-3][0-9]-([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])$"
birth_date = "MAR-31-1995"

if (re.search(pattern, birth_date)):
    print("Valid birth date.")
else:
    print("Invalid birth date.")
```

Comment: Your regexp will match up to the year 2999.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  My first, second, and third recommendations for working with Date objects are all the same: Never ever use home-cooked regexps. Use a Date library, every language has a few and Python (famously) has "Batteries Included". I always find I am better off using them.

Comment: Your use of `[]` around the months is totally wrong, that should be `()`.

Comment: And you shouldn't have spaces around the `|`.

Comment: That update worked. -- for days, `[1-3][0-9]` will not match single digits like `3`, `[1-3]?[0-9]` will work

Comment: Can you just do `& (int(birth_data.split('-')[2]) <= 2020)`? No other libraries are required. Also, if the day is `DD` don't you need to catch 01, 02, 03 ...09?

Comment: Does this require the use of regular expressions? Do you have to account for leap years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many indicated, using a regex is not necessarily the best choice. However being it an assignment, you are confined to the requirements.

The regex is a bit convoluted, especially if one needs to also perform restriction checks in-regex. That said, here's what I have come up with:

```
pattern ="^(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)-(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])-(1\d\d\d|20[01]\d|2020)$"
```

Note that you need to also make sure that - for example - months can at most have 31 days, which is accounted for in here. As for the year, I have split the range in three, where I left the first 1000 years open, and you can restrict those further easily.

Unfortunately, this particular solution still leaves it open to have `Feb 31st` as a valid date. A complete regex that also takes that into account can probably be built, but will become even more unreadable than this :-)

Hope this works.

See it in action here : https://regex101.com/r/ZNJXTQ/2

Answer (score 0):

I think regex might be the wrong tool for this job. You could use the `datetime.strptime` instead.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

```
import datetime as dt

def is_valid_birthday(date_str):
    dt_format = '%b-%d-%Y'
    try:
        birthday = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, dt_format).date()
        if birthday > dt.date.today():
            return False
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print(is_valid_birthday('Feb-17-2020'))
```